# Get all classes implementing given interface

Tags: java, android, maven, reflection, maven-plugin

I have interface `Datagram` and few classes that implements it, for example `A` and `B`.
At some point during runtime, I receive via Bluetooth object that implements given interface (which is `A` or `B`). I distinguish them by adding special class identifying number as a first byte of send message.

The point is that **I need an array of all classes implementing given interface**, so I could assign them to byte numbers. That number in unique identifier for class and I use it to get object from byte array, send via Bluetooth from another device.

Now it's done "manually" by creating array like `private static final Class[] datagramClasses = { A.class, B.class };`, but it's very incontinent way - if I add class `C` to my program, I need to append it to `datagramClasses` array too. Alternatively, I could send full class name in every `Datagram`, but it would be silly.

After doing some research, I've come up with few ideas:

1. Getting information (class name) from `.class` files and use `Class.forName("com.mypackage.A");`. But Android use single `.dex` file instead of `.class` files.
2. Use external library to do that - I've tried [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) and few others, but I was unable to compile them on Android platform. Is there any simpler library that would do the trick?
3. Creating Maven plugin, that would do the trick. I successfully added Maven to my Android project, but I was unable to compile some additional plugin developing related libraries (again, due to Android limitations). I could create another related project, in Java, and develop plugin there, but I worry that it'll be far too complicated.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Greg

edit: I'd expect to be able to execute code like:

```
final List<Class> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (final Class c : allAplicationClasses)
    if (isAssignableFrom(Datagram.class))
        list.add(c);
```

Comment: What about creating a static factory method in `Datagram` which would create instances of `A`, `B` etc according to contents?

Comment: why do you need that array?

Comment: @pskink I've edited my question, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently not sure if I understood your question entirely, but if you just want an array containing classes implementing the Datagram interface I would suggest something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<iDatagram> list = new ArrayList<iDatagram>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    list.add(new C());

    int i = 0;
    for (iDatagram item : list) {
        Log.i("class name", item.getName());

        if (item instanceof A) {
            Log.i("item at location "+i, item.getName());
        } 
        else if (item instanceof B) {
            Log.i("item at location "+i, item.getName());
        }
        else if (item instanceof C) {
            Log.i("item at location "+i, item.getName());
        }

        i++;
    }

}

interface iDatagram {
    String getName();
}

class A implements iDatagram {

    private String name = "I am class A";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class B implements iDatagram {

    private String name = "I am class B";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class C implements iDatagram {

    private String name = "I am class C";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No, it's not what I expected. I'd like to get all classes **without** defining `new A()` or `A.class`.

Comment: @gogowitczak why? why do tou need rhat array?